# how to efficiently compute private key in DSA with known parameters

Tags: dsa

For textbook DSA, as defined below. If $r, s, k, g, p, q, m$ are all known, is it possible to efficiently compute $x$ from all these given values? How does the math work out?

- Secret key: $x\stackrel R\gets \mathbb{Z}_{q}$
- Private key: $X=g^{x}\in \mathbb{Z}^{*}_{p}$
- Signature:
  $\text{Algorithm }S_x(M)\\\quad{
  m\gets H(M)\\
  k\stackrel\\\$\gets\mathbb Z_q^*\\
  r\gets(g^k\bmod p)\bmod q\\
  s\gets(m+x\,r)\,k^{-1}\bmod q\\
  \text{return }(r,s)}$
- Verification:
  $\text{Algorithm }V_X(M,(r,s))\\\quad{
  m\gets H(M)\\
  w\gets s^{-1}\bmod q\\
  u_1\gets m\,w\bmod q\\
  u_2\gets r\,w\bmod q\\
  v\gets(g^{u_1}\,X^{u_2}\bmod p)\bmod q\\
  \text{if }(v=r)\text{ return }1\\
  \text{else return }0}$

where $H$ is just SHA-1.

Comment: Better use `\stackrel r\gets` as [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/62674/18298)

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: I corrected the algorithms previously specified as images. $r$ is computed $\bmod p$, not $\bmod q$. And Algorithms $V$ is parametrized by $X$, not $x$. Also improved typo.

Comment: Hint: the critical difference with normal DSA is that in the question, $k$ is known.