# Notation for commitment schemes

Tags: commitments, notation

I was reading [this set of lecture notes](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos433/lec10.pdf) on commitment schemes, where they define a commitment scheme $\text{Com}(b, r) = f(r), h(r) \oplus b$ as a secure commitment scheme. In this case, $f : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ is a one-way permutation, $h : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is a hard-core bit of $f(\cdot)$, and $r$ appears to be a random string from $\{0,1\}^n$ (the notation is $r \leftarrow_R \{0,1\}^n$, but I'm not really sure what this actually means and it would be super helpful if someone could clarify what the notation means here!).

My question is what the $f(r), h(r) \oplus b$ means. What is the comma doing? Does this mean that the commitment scheme returns two outputs (I was under the impression that commitment schemes only return one output)? Or am I supposed to combine $f(r)$ with $h(r) \oplus b$ somehow? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or am I supposed to combine $f(r)$ with $h(r) \oplus b$ somehow?

Yes, $\text{Com}(b, r)$ is a function which "combines" them.  However it only "combines" them in the sense that it outputs the pair $f(r), h(r) \oplus b$

The main confusion here stems from not realizing that a tuple can be a perfectly valid singular output. (This is compounded by Boaz Barak writing the tuple without parentheses.)

From the lecture notes:

> **Definition 2** (Commitment schemes). A commitment scheme $Com$ is an unkeyed function
> that takes two inputs: a plaintext $x ∈ \{0,1\}^n$
> ` and randomness $r$ chosen in $\{0,1\}^n$. The
> idea is that to commit to the winner I let $x$ be my prediction, choose
> $r \leftarrow_R \{0,1\}^n$
> n and publish $y = Com(x, r)$. Later to prove I predicted $x$, I will publish $x$ and $r$.

---

> (the notation is $r \leftarrow_R \{0,1\}^n$, but I'm not really sure what this actually means and it would be super helpful if someone could clarify what the notation means here!).

On page 3 of the notes, the author uses $R$ to indicate random. $\gets$ is assignment.
$\gets_R$ is used for uniform random assignment.

For more see [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34799/what-is-meaning-of-operator-in-cryptography/62674#62674).

Comment: "Yes, $\text{Com}(b, r)$ is a function which combines them." I'm not sure what you mean by that. It only "combines" them in the sense that it outputs the pair $(f(r),h(r)\oplus b)$. I think the main confusion in the question stems from not realizing that a tuple can be a perfectly valid singular output. (This is compounded by Boaz Barak writing the tuple without parentheses.)

Comment: Thank you so much!